# Best way to fetch dynamic data from server in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, greendao

I am new in android and developing an android application in which admin can insert data on server and users can load that data on their devices. I don't want to load data from server every time user land on that activity. I want to save fetched data at client side using greendao and load only the new one. And i think i have to hit the backend at least once. I am looking for a most convenient method to achieve this.

Comment: You could notify users when changes are pending: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream But I'd back that up with some wider interval in that a poll is forced. But you could optimize that poll in that only a version parameter is checked against the server and real data update is only done if server data is newer. Just what first came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way would be to track the device on the server side:

for example create a table like `cachedDevices(deviceId,dataId)`. then whenever you are requesting new data, your server could query  your data against `cachedDevices` internally and only send new data...

you should also be aware of that each device should have unique Id...